# Eclipse can not commit all files to Git

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I have project in eclipse. I was developing it. Everything was fine. I use git to commit changes.

But starting from some point I noticed that not all files in git repository are committed.
When I do **commit**, git just do not show it under list of available files. I have tried to commit each file - no result, tried "add to index" - no result.
Does somebody know what can be the reason? I have such problem first time.

And no tracking symbol "`>`" appears.

Comment: Any changes to your `gitinore` file?

Answer (score 1):

In order to see if there is an issue with a `.gitignore`, switch back to the command line, and type:

```
git check-ignore -v -- yourFile
```

You will immediately see if one of the `.gitignore` rules applies to it or not.

Comment: @ovod Simple: unzip anywhere you want https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.4.windows.2/PortableGit-2.4.4.2-3rd-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe, add `<path/to/PortableGit-2.4.4.2-3rd-release-candidate-64-bit\bin>` to your `%PATH%` and you have git in command line.